# Image not being loaded in Picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, loadimage

I am trying to load this Image : http://api.aircountr.com/3UE2c8CtxmzZfRan0hex5uWGkmzl0BWG.jpg

But using picasso it is not being loaded. I have gone through lot of similar questions but didn't find the solution.

Every time I am getting onError() callback.

```
if (mDataList.get(position).getImageUrl() != null && !mDataList.get(position).getImageUrl().equals("")) {
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(mDataList.get(position).getImageUrl().trim()).into(iv_invoiceImg, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d("rajcheck", "success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.d("rajcheck", "fail" + ""+mDataList.get(pos).getImageUrl().trim()+"a");
                }
            });
        } else iv_invoiceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_logo);
```

**UPDATE - Problem Solved**
The image URL was not containing "http://" that was the problem.

Comment: just debug and get the string url which you are pasing to the picasso there might be some issue with url. it happens that sometime you get  \/ instead of // then u need to encode the string to a valid url

Comment: I have checked it and there is no error in URL

Comment: mContext might be null. did you checked that?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have gave permission for App to access `internet` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission-sdk-23>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

First change this condition

```
if (mDataList.get(position).getImageUrl() != null && !mDataList.get(position).getImageUrl().equals("")) {
```

to

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mDataList.get(position).getImageUrl()))
```

After seeing your image it is not thumbnail image so it is taking too much time to load.

So in `onSuccess()` method load your real image using

```
@Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(mDataList.get(position).getImageUrl()) 
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                    .into(iv_invoiceImg);
        }
```

Comment: But onSuccess() is not getting called

Comment: Just check are you able to get _mDataList.get(position).getImageUrl()_. Also did u change your condition as i said

Comment: Yes I logged it in onError() and it is returning same URL which I posted in my question

Comment: Also did u change your condition as i said

Comment: Is there a problem because of the Image Size?

Comment: Yes I changed that condition

Comment: Yes it is .. You can use transform for that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114692/discussion-between-raj-patel-and-piyush-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your url and its working on my side

please check

In manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

MainActivity

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load("http://api.aircountr.com/3UE2c8CtxmzZfRan0hex5uWGkmzl0BWG.jpg")
                .into(imgView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });
```

Output[image]

Comment: Yes the problem was with the URL it was not containing http://
what a silly mistake